# Tedious package giving error "undefined is not a function" with es6,React,webpack

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, electron, tedious

I am trying to connect to a remote mysql server using connection strings with the help of tedious library.
 i converted all my code from react to react-es6.
 when i try to make a connection as below, i get an error "undefined is not a function".

```
    class APP extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        alert("hai");
        console.log("hai");
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            result: [],
            RecNo: ""
        };
    }
    getZipData(){
        alert("hello");
        var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
        console.log("connection:"+Connection)
        Request = require('tedious').Request;
        console.log("request:"+Request);
        var config = {
            userName: 'xx',
            password: 'xxxxxx',
            server: 'xxxxxxxxx', 
            options: {
                database: 'xxxxxxx'
            }
        };
        alert("shaik"+JSON.stringify(config));
        var connection = new Connection(config);   //getting error here
        alert("connected")
        connection.on('connect',(err)=> {
            console.log("connected");
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
           //executeStatement();
            var sql = "SELECT * FROM xxxx";
            return new Promise(
                function(resolve,reject){
                    var data = [];
                    var request = new Request(sql,[],(row)=>{
                            data.push(row);
                        },
                        (error)=>{
                            if(error){
                                reject(error);
                            }else{
                                resolve(data);
                            }
                        });
                }
            )
            connection.execSql(request);
            console.log("hai:")
        });
   }

      componentWillMount() {
    this.getZipData()
        alert("data:");
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <p>Hello</p>
        )
    }
}
React.render(<APP/>,document.getElementById('app'));
```

I am not able to establish a connection.perhaps there could be a syntax error as i am new to this.

Comment: What line are you getting that error?

Comment: var connection = new Connection(config);

Comment: In which case, `require('tedious').Connection` returns `undefined`.

Comment: I am getting error in the line ,
var connection = new Connection(config); 
in  the tedious module connection.js file: this.socket = new Socket({});
getting error that undefined is not a function

Answer (score 0):

This is because, probably, the Connection object is not supposed to be used on the Browser. Because it connects to a DB or something.

You should create a jS module to interact with this Connection through Ajax calls and import it into your component.